# Trouble using hooks in my Custom react UI Kit after install Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, uikit, vite

[ui kit vite config for build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Okb.png)

I have been trying to utilize hooks in a UI Kit library, but I'm encountering issues. I have attempted different approaches, but none of them have been successful so far. I'm using either React for my project. if after install ui kit on other next js project get error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')`
Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly integrate hooks in a UI Kit library with either Next.js or React? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

[card component (used other project)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/csXyk.png)

[error when use it in other project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYC3Q.png)

`react version: 18`
`next.js version: 13`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From NextJS 13 and above, every page/component is by default a [Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#composing-client-and-server-components) if you are using app directory.

You are getting this error because in Server component we cannot use hooks.

One Solution for this error would be to make your component a `Client Component` in which you are using a hooks by adding "use client" directive at top of file.

Example:

```js
"use client";

import { Card } from "some-library"

function CardLayout() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Card />
       <Card />
       <Card />
     </div>
   )
}
```

And then use this component in you page.